# Set Specific Database for EXPDP - Two Oracle Databases

Tags: oracle, expdp

I have installed 2 oracle databases (i.e) 2 different instances in a server. From Username, Password, SID, Listener everything is different. Like Mentioned Below.

**Instance 1:**
Username : TEST
Password : TEST123
Port : 1111
SID : ForTest

**Instance 2:**
Username : NEW
Password : NEW123
Port : 2222
SID : ForNew

I am trying to export a table from Instance 1, by giving the following EXPDP command.

```
EXPDP TEST/TEST123@ForTest DIRECTORY=EXP_DIREC DUMPFILE=MAP_TABLE.DMP version=11.1 TABLES=MAP_TABLE
```

I am getting the exception like,

```
UDE-12154: operation generated ORACLE error 12154
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

Where can i specify, that the export should use specific instance.

Comment: ForTest is the connect identifier that you should have in your tnsnames.ora. Another way is to use the connect string like this (for **Instance 1**): `EXPDP TEST/TEST123@"(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=YourHostName)(Port=1111)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=ForTest)))" DIRECTORY=EXP_DIREC DUMPFILE=MAP_TABLE.DMP version=11.1 TABLES=MAP_TABLE`. There is even a shorter way called EzConnect, but it requires the usage of service names and, depending on your OS, some quotes escaping.

Comment: In the Second way i am going, but getting the exception as,   LRM-00116: syntax error at 'ADDRESS_LIST' following '('

Comment: Try this: `EXPDP TEST/TEST123@\"(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=YourHostNa‌​me)(Port=1111)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=ForTest)))\" DIRECTORY=EXP_DIREC DUMPFILE=MAP_TABLE.DMP version=11.1`

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is working fine.

Comment: That's the escaping I was talking about :)

Comment: I haven't look at the last point. Anyhow..once again thanks a lot..:)

Answer (score 0):

You already specified the instance

Try login to it

sqlplus  is/pass@sid

and note error

check tnsnames and listener file

Cheers
Brian